# Finding the isomorphisms of posets of $S_4$ and $S_5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $S_n$ be the poset of all subsets of $\{1,2,3,\ldots, n \}$. Let $D_n$ be the poset of factors of $n$ under relation of divisibility. We are given that $D_{30}$ is isomorphic to $S_3$ and are to find what is isomorphic to $S_4$ and $S_5$.

From extending the relationship given I got the following:

$S_4$ is isomorphic to $D_{210}$

$S_5$ is isomorphic to $D_{2310}$

Did I extend the relationship correctly or did I miss something?

EDIT: This is due to the prime factorization of the n in ${D_n}$. 210 is 30 x 7 and 2310 is 210 x 11. When you add another prime factor, it adds another base level to the poset. This is what makes it isomorphic to ${S_n}$.

Comment: That looks correct to me. Can you explain the isomorphism?

Comment: You appear to have found the smallest correct solutions.  There are, of course, infinitely many other solutions.

Comment: When you submit your solution you should mention the prime factorization.